# How to update xml file in war file?

Tags: java, tomcat6, war

I have war which working in production. I need to change the web.xml and again i need to make war file to deploy.Since we are changing xml file, so no need compliation at all..But i don't have source code to create war file again.

if change the xml file which will work again ? if yes how to create war file in command prompt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WARs are just zip files with `.war`as extension, so you just have to :

- extract the WAR into some directory
- replace `web.xml` in `WEB-INF`
- zip the directory content into a file using the same filename than before.

BTW, try to deploy your repackaged WAR into some production-like environment to test if application is running like you want.